# Switch case goes to default except one case

Tags: c#, winforms

when i tried to use the Switch case function, it goes always to the default message besides case 5:

```
private void btnCandlesLight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int result;
        result = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        switch(result)
        {
            case 1:
                day1.Start();
                candlesOne();
                break;
            case 2:
                day2.Start();
                candlesTwo();
                break;
            case 3:
                day3.Start();
                candlesThree();
                break;
            case 4:
                day4.Start();
                candlesFour();
                break;
            case 5:
                day5.Start();
                candlesFive();
                break;
            case 6:
                day6.Start();
                candlesSix();
                break;
            case 7:
                day7.Start();
                candlesSeven();
                break;
            case 8:
                day8.Start();
                candlesEight();
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Enter new day");
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I Enter the value 1 for example to the text box, the default case works, but only when I enter the value 5 it works perfectly.
If you want to see the difference between the function "candlesOne" to "candlesFive":

The "c" variable is a variable of the seconds. i tried to use a timer in a way of lighting up the candles every 2-3 seconds.

```
public void candlesOne()
    {
        firedmatch.Left = firedmatch.Left + 100;
        if (c == 1)
        {
            candle1.Visible = true;
        }
        if (c == 3)
        {
            candle2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

and:

```
public void candlesFive()
    {
        firedmatch.Left = firedmatch.Left + 100;
        if(c == 1)
        {
            candle1.Visible = true;
        }
        if(c == 3)
        {
            candle2.Visible = true;
        }
        if(c == 5)
        {
            candle3.Visible = true;
        }
        if(c == 7)
        {
            candle4.Visible = true;
        }
        if(c == 11)
        {
            candle5.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

I haven't found a mistake,
can you guys help me?
Thanks

Comment: Put a break point and check result value in ur code.

Comment: Try to debug the value of result. Looks like it isn't what you are expecting.

Comment: The code you've provided isn't a [mcve]. We can't possibly know what is wrong without seeing all the related code. There's a mysterious variable called `c`, for example.

Comment: On a positive note, today is already 2 Tevet so you can just fudge it with a `const`, light all the candles, and take the rest of next year to debug this.  You might also take the time to think of a better way to do this - consider perhaps [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_CalendarSystem_GetHebrewCalendar.htm) - read the actual date and light the appropriate candles ;)

Comment: Ah - "i tried to use a timer in a way of lighting up the candles every 2-3 seconds." - you should have said that from the first. This is what you're actually trying to do. All the rest of the code doesn't matter if you can get your candles to light up. Can you explain what the how each candle should light up over time?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked if you really get for example `(int)1` as a result of the "1" input from your conversion?

On a broader scale, there is a lot of repetition in your code, you should consider refactoring it a little.

In your CandlesOne and CandlesFive methods, you use a `c` variable, no idea what that is or where it comes from. Those two methods (and probably the other `CandlesXXX()` do the same kind of things. Can't you remove complexity by generalizing the logic? Can the `result` used in your switch-case be passed as a parameter and used to trigger the numbers of `c == X` calls in the `CandleXXX()` methods?

This way you could remove the switch and lose a lot of complexity!

**Edit**

If you have further problems, consider creating a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), I miss a lot of context in your code so I cannot efficiently help you here.

Some refactoring ideas for you:

```
// Somewhere else in your code, create a dictionary with your day1-day8 objects
var days = new Dictionary<int, Day>()
days[1] = day1;
...
days[8] = day8;

//Simplfiy your method
private void btnCandlesLight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var dayIndex = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        if(dayIndex > 0 && dayIndex <= 8)
        {
            days[dayIndex].Start(); //Get the corresponding day via its Key
            LightUpCandles(dayIndex); //pass the key as a parameter
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter new day");
        }
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException exception)
    {
        //Whatever you do when the textbox cannot be parsed
    }
}
```

I still don't get what your candlesOne to five methods are really doing or why the method "candlesOne" lights up two candles (pay attention to the variable naming). I also don't get how this makes up some kind of timer... but here's a first potential refactoring for it anyway:

```
public void LightUpCandles(int dayIndex)
{
    firedmatch.Left = firedmatch.Left + 100;
    if(c == 1)
    {
        candle1.Visible = true;
    }
    if(c == 3 && dayIndex > 1)
    {
        candle2.Visible = true;
    }
    if(c == 5 && dayIndex > 2)
    {
        candle3.Visible = true;
    }
    if(c == 7 && dayIndex > 3)
    {
        candle4.Visible = true;
    }
    if(c == 11 && dayIndex > 4)
    {
        candle5.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The "c" variable is a variable of the seconds. i tried to use a timer in a way of lighting up the candles every 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch logic is correct which I tested with the following;

```
int result;
        result = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        switch (result)
        {
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("1");
                break;
            case 2:
                MessageBox.Show("2");
                break;
            case 3:
                MessageBox.Show("3");
                break;
            case 4:
                MessageBox.Show("4");
                break;
            case 5:
                MessageBox.Show("5");
                break;
            case 6:
                MessageBox.Show("6");
                break;
            case 7:
                MessageBox.Show("7");
                break;
            case 8:
                MessageBox.Show("8");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Enter new day");
                break;
        }
```

If you don't get the same results I would perhaps look at making the message boxes above display the data type of the variable.

```
MessageBox.Show(result.GetType().ToString());
```

Comment: i deleted the default just to check if the problem is in the variables, and it still shows me the default

Comment: @H.Astrin, stop and think about what you just said there. If you removed the default, rebuilt the code and ran it once more, it cannot show you the default. Sounds like your code isn't compiling and/or you are running an old version. Try cleaning/rebuilding your solution.

Comment: @DavidArno Exactly what i'm trying to say. It is very weird. Can you explain to me what can cause this problem? it happened me in the past, in my personal computer, my laptop, and in the computer in my school, and i'm running the most updated version of VS13

Comment: @H.Astrin If you removed the default, and its still performing it, your program will definitely be using an old version, there may be an error which is preventing a new version from being compiled. Are there any errors on your display?